# Is there a way to convert HEX color into visual color in HTML, CSS or Python?

Tags: html, css, mongodb, flask, python-3.6

I have been working on a project with forms in HTML to understand more about MongoDB, CSS, HTML, Python. I used Flask to put Python, HTML and CSS together in PyCharm. While I was testing my code to see if it would import into MongoDB's Atlas, I saw that the color had been stored in HEX. Is there any way to take a HEX color and turn it into visual color? Here is the code from the form where (depending on the browser and Operation System) shows a color picker.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form Page</title>
    <style>
        body{
        background-color:lightblue;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <h1>Random Form to learn about Forms in HTML</h1>
    <h3>Enter your first name</h3>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your first name" name="first_name">
    <h3>Enter your last name</h3>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your last name" name="last_name">
    <h3>Are you male or female</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="Gender"value="Male">
    <label>Male</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Gender"value="Female">
    <label>Female</label>
    <br>
    <h3>Select your favorite color</h3>
    <input type="color" name="color">
    <h3>Enter your date of birth</h3>
    <input type="datetime" name="date">
    <h3>Enter an email we can contact you at</h3>
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit"></form>


</body>
</html>
```

The next side code snippet will be the display page where everyone can see people who have submitted the form. Here is the MongoDB page since you do not have access to the other page:

[Image of MongoDB Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yEgB.png)

As you can see in the image, the photo shows a HEX color. Most people do not understand HEX so is there some type of code that I can use (3rd party or not) that can convert it into a visual color? Thanks

Comment: It's not clear where you want the color to appear. In your MongoDB admin screen?

Comment: I want the color to appear on the screen. I want to convert a HEX color number to visual color that I can recognize. This will show up as a HEX number in MongoDB Admin Screen, but will show as visual color in a results page in html.